# When does a static data table memory is disposed

Tags: c#, iis-7.5

I have a method which will return me more than 1,00,000 records and I had stored them in a static data table, and this data table is bound to grid view which is paginated.

where is this static data table stored and when is it disposed.

My app is residing on iis 7.5 server

Comment: Static data like this stays around for as long as the application is running, or until you free it manually.

Comment: My application is a session based application will the memory reside on server until this session is active or it will reside on server until the app pool is restarted

Comment: Static data stays across sessions. So until app pool is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored on the AppDomain and is disposed when your appdomain is unloaded.

Answer (score 2):

- Static variables are stored in the IIS Worker Process memory.
- As long as they are referenced, they'll not be disposed.
- And they'll be gone when the worker process recycles or when the web app is stopped.
- Static data stays across sessions.